# Finding record of immigration to Argentina from Spain?

Tags: 20th-century, immigration, spain, argentina

I have lost track of a relative when he took a ship to Argentina from Spain.

His name was Pedro Peñalba Águeda (born around 1890-1900), and our oral history says that he took a ship named *Conte Rosso* from Lloyd Sabaudo S.A. di Navigazione to Argentina.

I have been able to investigate that such ship has been travelling between Europe and Argentina between 1922 and 1931. He joined the ship in A Coruña. I do not know the city the ship stopped in Argentina.

In the available passenger list of the *Conte Rosso* he does not appear, but it really looks like that list is missing a significant number of its passengers.

Any hint how can I progress in the research?

Comment: What is the evidence that he joined that particular ship?  Is it perhaps from an oral history, obituary, or something else?

Comment: Oral history. Contact was lost after taking the ship

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have great news for you. :)

A 24 years old single man called Pedro Penalba Agueda arrived in Buenos Aires on 1930/03/18. The ship was "Conte Rosso".

You can run the search here: https://cemla.com/buscador/

Note that the last name appears as "Penalba", not Ñ but N.
This could be an error when he arrived, or an electronic misspelling when loading the information to the current database.

In my experience, some of the first electronic databases did not support the character ñ/Ñ. On future searches keep that in mind and try both "Peñalba" and "Penalba", just in case.

Also, note that in Argentina we tend to suppress the second last name, so if you try to locate him on other documents he could appear registered just as "Pedro Peñalba" or "Pedro Penalba".

Comment: Thanks! Strange... I used the same site and only adding one of the surnames was not possible to find any match, only with the 2 surnames worked... I learnt something about the site. Concerning further research in Argentina, is there any guidance of how to continue?